# Using `any` and `all` as logical tests over multiple elements within `case_when`?

Tags: r, dplyr

As you can see from the examples below, column A has multiple elements of different lengths. I'm trying to use `case_when` within a `mutate` call to create categorical columns that 'tag' subsets of these multiple elements.

For example, we create a dummy dataset:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~A, ~B,
  c("a", "b", "c", "1", "2"), "alpha",
  c("b", "c", "d", "1"), "beta",
  c("c", "d", "1", "2", "3"), "gamma"
)
```

And then to evaluate subset membership I'm using `any` and `all` over an `%in%` call, like so:

```
result <- df %>%
  mutate(
    test = case_when(all(c("a","1") %in% A) ~ "x",
                     any(c("beta","gamma") %in% B) ~ "y")
  )
```

Here, I'm expecting `result$test` to show `x`, `y`, `y`. Instead I'm getting `NA`s.

Is my approach possible? If not, what's the reason and what's the most efficient alternative strategies I could implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you may need `rowwise`

```
df %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(test = case_when(all(c("a","1") %in% A) ~ "x",
                     any(c("beta","gamma") %in% B) ~ "y"))
```

which gives

```
  A         B     test
  <list>    <chr> <chr>
1 <chr [5]> alpha x
2 <chr [4]> beta  y
3 <chr [5]> gamma y
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `purrr`'s `map2_chr` to iterate over the list values of `A`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(test = purrr::map2_chr(A, B, ~case_when(all(c("a","1") %in% .x) ~ "x",
                                          any(c("beta","gamma") %in% .y) ~ "y")))

#   A         B     test 
#  <list>    <chr> <chr>
#1 <chr [5]> alpha x    
#2 <chr [4]> beta  y    
#3 <chr [5]> gamma y
```